# Automated Chat Animation

Tags: liveagent

I am using Auto Chat invite on one of our company pages and the invite gets triggered again after "x" number of seconds of customer rejecting the invite.

Is this because i have selected " Allow invitation to be triggered again after rejecting" ? I thought that this would trigger invite only on page refresh after the customer rejects the invite. Does this setting send invites after rejection even without the page refresh ?

Can someone confirm my understanding above ?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. The live agent API keeps evaluates the auto-invite criteria every few seconds regardless of any page refresh.